# MockK verify return value

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I need to verify that a function is being called. When I run debug, I can see it being called but I get this error from `mockk`:

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Object(#2).f(any(), any())) was not called.
```

My verify statemen is as follows:

```
verify(exactly = 1) { object.f(any(), any()) }
```

And I create the spy object as follows:

```
object = spyk(object)
```

The signature of the function `f` is:

```
f(any(), any()) : String
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction, how do I use verify for the function `f`. I suspect that because the function `f` returns a string, `verify` cannot match it's signature.

In any case, please let me know if you have an idea of why verify doesn't work in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full source code `object` as well as your test case?